# Tilted TIFF images, how to make them look exact?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I've two TIFF layers in my QGIS project. My plan is to find differences and mark them with some attributes. The tiffs are from two different sources. If you notice the GIF file, you can see one of them is tilted. I don't know how to solve this issue. I tried with different projections but no use.

I'm new to QGIS.

[image: tilted image]

Comment: Obviously not only one but both aerial images are tilted. AFAIK there is no solution to this problem besides taking true orthophotos with small tiles to compensate for distortions introduced by the natural lens curvature. Your only option seems to look for other sources of aerial images / orthophotos which are taken from more fitting angles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two images have been taken with a different viewing angle, therefore you have a horizontal displacement that is linked with the height difference (look for "parallax" for more information on this topic). It is possible to make a true orthophoto (that is, remove all the effects of parallax, if you have a precise Digital Surface Model (created from a pair of images or derived from LIDAR data). Unfortunately, many georeferenced images only take into account the base height during the orthorectification process. As a result, only the positions of ground lying objects are reliable. Once you have an "incomplete" orthophoto, it is no more possible to precisely adjust the position of the vertical objects for the whole image because you cannot infer the viewing angles anymore.

For your practical issue, under the constraint of your images, you could at least try to co-register the ground element (see warp tool in the raster menu). Then you could reduce the number of false detections by using a tolerance based on maximum viewing angle and height of the building.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure for what its worth. They both have different CRS - IGS08/GRS80 and NAD83/GRS80.

Comment: This could explain the shift/tilt of the swimming pool, but not the building. When you have the same GRS, there is usually no risk of errors with on the fly projection.